# How do we listen to Solidity Smart Contract events on React.js?

Tags: reactjs, solidity

I'm trying to implement a basic login functionality using Solidity. The function takes in 1 string argument which is a password, matches it with the user's password stored in a struct in the smart contract, and fires an event with a bool variable, which will be true if the passwords match and false if they don't.
I have no clue how to listen to this event in React.js.

I tried using the watch() function but it doesn't seem to be working. I read somewhere that the watch() function might not work in this case.

```
event LoginSuccessful(
        bool success
    );
function Login
        (string memory _password)
        public
    {
        if(keccak256(bytes(users[msg.sender].password)) == keccak256(bytes(_password)))
            emit LoginSuccessful(true);
        else
            emit LoginSuccessful(false);
    }
```

Comment: Can you share the piece of code where you are using `watch` function?

Comment: Might be useful https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-subscribe.html

Comment: This one too https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.0/web3-eth-contract.html#once

Answer (score 0):

Simply useEffect hook can be used to look upon events in reactJS.

A general syntax to catch events

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // initializing provider and dai contract instance
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        abiCode,
        provider
    );

    // caching the emitted event
    contract && contract.on("eventName", eve => {
        console.log("Some event is emmited");
    })
})
```

In your code it can be customized as below

```
 useEffect(() => {
    // initializing provider and dai contract instance
    const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider();
    const contract = new ethers.Contract(
        contractAddress,
        abiCode,
        provider
    );

    // caching the emitted event
    contract && contract.on("LoginSuccessful", (success) => {
        console.log("Output: ", success);
    })
})
```